# Why would it failed to use " tail -fn0 output.log | grep error >> error.log " in Linux

Tags: linux, sh

I want to write a shell script to keep watching my logs

some how I write

```
 tail -fn0 output.log | grep error >> error.log
```

would not output the logs contain "error" to error.log

If I write

```
 tail -fn0 output.log | \
    while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | grep error >>error.log
    done
```

and it would work perfectly

I just want to know why can't I write like

```
tail -fn0 output.log | grep error >> error.log
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `grep --line-buffered`:

```
tail -f output.log | grep --line-buffered error >> error.log
```

To reproduce the solution, use this example:

```
for i in `seq 1 10` ; do echo "error $i"; sleep 10; done > output.log &
rm error.log
tail -f output.log | grep --line-buffered error >> error.log &
head output.log error.log
```

Output:

```
head output.log error.log
==> output.log <==
error 1
error 2
error 3
...

==> error.log <==
error 1
error 2
error 3
...
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

> `--line-buffered`
> Use line buffering for standard output, regardless of output device. By default, standard output is line buffered for
> interactive devices, and is fully buffered otherwise. With full
> buffering, the output buffer is flushed when full; with line
> buffering, the buffer is also flushed after every output line. The
> buffer size is system dependent.